# how to add column on table using query builder in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to add a column in my existing table in Laravel but not using migration. Is there any way to add column like this?

Comment: Through database tools such as PHPMyAdmin / SQL Yog etc. etc.

Comment: But then you'd break your migration which I wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DB::statement() function, from the *DB Facade*, according to their [database documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database) like this:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype');
```

Though, it's **not recommended**.

The place for this things are in migrations for a reason, so you won't perform this more than once and you won't be executing creating or dropping columns dynamically (which shouldn't be).

So, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement() function ---work for me 

DB::connection('mysql')->statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name int   NULL DEFAULT(1)');

For all tables:

 foreach ($alltable as $key => $table)
 {
   DB::connection('mysql')->statement('ALTER TABLE '.$table1.' ADD store_id int   
   NULL DEFAULT(1)');
 }
```